# Bundle service - Attempted to load class from namespace

Tags: symfony, service, bundle

In my symfony project I have two bundles.
My first bundle (Bundle1) is the main bundle and the second one (Bundle2) is used to store some services.

Here is my service.yml (Bundle2):

```
services:
   sc_ezpublish_helpers.generic_find:
      class: SC\EzPublishHelpersBundle\Helper\GenericFindHelper
```

And in Bundle1 I use call my service like this :

```
$findHelper = $this->get( 'sc_ezpublish_helpers.generic_find' );
```

After clearing the cache I have this error :

> Attempted to load class "GenericFindHelper" from namespace "SC\EzPublishHelpersBundle\Helper".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

**Stack Trace**

in app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 20582   -

```
 */
protected function getScEzpublishHelpers_GenericFindService()
{
    return $this->services['sc_ezpublish_helpers.generic_find'] = new \SC\EzPublishHelpersBundle\Helper\GenericFindHelper($this->get('ezpublish.signalslot.repository'), $this->get('ezpublish.config.resolver.core'));
}
/**
```

Here is my autoload in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

And here is my Bundle2 structure

```
src/
├── SC
│   └── EzPublishHelpersBundle
│       ├── DependencyInjection
│       │   ├── Configuration.php
│       │   └── SCEzPublishHelpersExtension.php
│       ├── Helpers
│       │   └── GenericFindHelper.php
│       ├── Resources
│       │   └── config
│       │       └── services.yml
│       └── SCEzPublishHelpersBundle.php
```

Do you have an idea ? Did I forgot something ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like an autoloading issue. Can you check that the folder structure matches the namespace and maybe add the autoload section from your composer.json here

Comment: I renamed my bundle, maybe because of that ? But I searched everywhere and i can't find if i forgot something... And i updated my message with my autoload

Comment: In that case please show your folder structure. The file should be located at `src/SC/EzPublishHelpersBundle/Helper/GenericHelper.php`

Comment: I added my Bundle2 structure. I deleted my old bundle (the one i renamed) and recreate a new bundle with the excepted name. But i got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mismatch between directory name and namespace. In your folder structure it's called `Helpers` (with a plural s) and in your namespace you use `Helper`. The autoloader uses the folder names to match to the classname, so you either have to specify this mismatch in your autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "SC\\EzPublishHelpersBundle\\Helper\\": "src/SC/EzPublishHelpersBundle/Helpers/",
        "": "src/"
    }
}
```

or (probably the easier and more common way) rename the folder to Helper.

<strike>The same goes for the class name by the way. If your `GenericHelper` class is in the file `GenericFindHelper.php` then the autoloader will not be able to match the filename to the class name. So please rename the file or use the classmap-autoloader for this specific file, if it is absolutely important to you to keep the name and namespace.</strike>

edit: I just noticed the wrong class name was just a typo in my reply. In your example it matches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I didn’t seen that. I will try tonight and tell you if everything is OK

Comment: It works fine, thanks you very much. I checked again and again and didn't seen the mismatch...
Thanks :)